# How do I bind a method to the root of a self hosted WCF webservice?

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf

I would like to call a method from a web service when the requested URL is the root of the host.

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface ICalculator
{
  [OperationContract]
  [WebGet(UriTemplate = "/")]
  string RootMethod(); 

  [OperationContract]
  [WebGet]
  double Add(double x, double y); 
}
```

Browsing to http://localhost/Add?x=1.1&y=2.2 `Add()` is executed and returns the result as expected, but when I browse to http://localhost/, `RootMehtod()` is not executed instead I get a message that tells me

> Metadata publishing for this service is currently disabled.

How do I bind a method to the root of a self hosted WCF webservice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all the error your are encountering is because you haven’t configured our service to expose any meta data about it.  To expose a WSDL for a service we need to configure our service to provide meta information.

Now, you need to update your OperationContract like this :

```
[OperationContract]

[WebGet(UriTemplate = "")]
```

Note the difference in UriTemplate

After that you need to expose end-point like this :

```
        string baseAddress = "http://" + Environment.MachineName;

        ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(TestService), new Uri(baseAddress));

        ServiceEndpoint endpoint = host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(ITestService), new WebHttpBinding(), "");

        endpoint.Behaviors.Add(new WebHttpBehavior());

        ServiceDebugBehavior debugBehavior = host.Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceDebugBehavior>();

        debugBehavior.HttpHelpPageEnabled = false;

        debugBehavior.HttpsHelpPageEnabled = false;

        host.Open();
```

Refer this [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/9141eb17-ac59-4ee1-9ce2-e313b08c247b/how-to-route-to-a-default-service-method?forum=wcf) for more details , hope this helps !

Comment: Thanks @ankit I don't need the wsdl meta data, what I missed was the `debugBehavior.HttpHelpPageEnabled = false;`